# How to reference formula in cell that is referencing another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Say I have a cell O5 in Sheet1 that has the following formula =Sheet2!B21.

I want Q5, R5, and S5 to point to Sheet2!D21, Sheet2!E21, and Sheet2!F21, respectively.

How can I make Q5, R5, and S5 change their row number whenever I change O5's?

For example, if I change O5 from =Sheet2!B21 to =Sheet2!B22, Q5, R5, and S5 should all automatically change to Sheet2!D22, Sheet2!E22, and Sheet2!F22, respectively.

I have looked into INDIRECT, but have not seen that it can snip parts of the formula in O5 (meaning to grab only the row numbers) and LEFT/RIGHT/MID also only grab the text in O5, not the formula, so haven't proven useful so far.  Thank you!

Comment: If the different cells need to point to a common row number, store that row number in a cell as an input value and incorporate that cell into each reference.  Change the cell and the references will all adjust.

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question, I was able to use VLOOKUP to condition on the results from the relevant column.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! I'm glad you found the solution to your problem on your own. Could you describe more precisely how you used `VLOOKUP` to help those who may have the same problem? And when you're done, you can mark your answer as Accepted. Thank you!